# How to find multiple sets of specific words from a paragraph in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say i have a paragraph like this:

```
String str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";
```

`setA` will contain words like Lorem, text, dummy.
`setB` will contain words like Ipsum, printing, industry.
`setC` will contain words like Lorem, text, dummy,Ipsum, printing, industry.

And after that

```
if(str.equals(set A))
{
  Some logic
}
else if{
  Set B logic
}
else{
 Set C logic
}
```

How do I code this in java?

Comment: Did you already try something?

Comment: Ya i tried using StringUtils. But i just started learning java and that was a bit tough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is weird solution but it can help you in a long paragraphs, so usually i use `String::matches` with some regex like :

```
//Only one word
(?i)(?=.*\bword\b).*
//-----------^

//Multiple words
(?i)(?=.*\bword1\b).*(?=.*\bword2\b).*
//---------^-----------------^
```

So the idea is simple, create a patter for your words, then use matches to verify if paragraph contain all the words or not :

**Code example :**

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String as[]) {
        String str = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and "
            + "typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's "
            + "standard dummy text ever since the 1500s";

        String setA = "Lorem, text, dummy";
        String setB = "Ipsum, printing, industry";
        String setC = "Lorem, text, dummy,Ipsum, printing, industry";
        Main m = new Main();

        if (str.matches(m.getPattern(setA))) {
            //Do something
        } else if (str.matches(m.getPattern(setB))) {
            //Do something
        } else if (str.matches(m.getPattern(setC))) {
            //Do something
        }

    }

   //The important method
   private String getPattern(String words) {
       StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words.split(",\\s*")));
       Arrays.asList(words.split(",\\s*"))
               .stream()
               .map(t -> "(?=.*\\b" + t + "\\b).*")
               .forEach(pattern::append);
       return "(?i)" + pattern.toString();
   }
}
```

---

The method `getPattern` will take a list of words `setA`, `setB`, `setC` ..., it can be any thing, then in :

1. (1) split this words for example for setA it will gives you `[Lorem, text, dummy]` (I consider that the input are a String for that i use split, if you have a collection you can avoid using split and use this collection like it is)
2. (2) loop throw the list of words to create a pattern, that you can use it later to matches your input (I use Stream of Java 8 instead of an ordinary loop to simplify the creation of the pattern).

So for example : for `setA` it will return a pattern like this `(?i)(?=.*\bLorem\b).*(?=.*\btext\b).*(?=.*\bdummy\b).*`, which can match any paragraphe which contain **all the words** `Lorem` and `text` and dummy

check the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ia7yEy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like these:

```
public boolean hasAny( final String txt, final Collection<String> words )
{
   for ( final String word : words )
      if ( txt.contains( word ) )
         return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean hasAll( final String txt, final Collection<String> words )
{
   boolean result = true;
   for ( final String word : words )
     result &= txt.contains( word );
   return result;
}
```

Similar could be done with Java8 streams, too...

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect an integer return for each set telling you the number of apparitions, or a boolean telling you if there are multiple apparitions of each set?

I would count the number of apparitions of each word of the set in the string and return the lowest value, or return a boolean when count of each apparition is >=2, depending what you want to do.

We would first have an structure of type

```
Map<Integer,String> setA = new HashMap<Integer,String>();// Integer is the number of apparitions of the String in the set
```

PseudoCode:

```
For each set{
For each word in the set{
count_of_word=str.count_number_of_apparitions_of(word)
}
for each word in the set{
if count_of_word<min_count_of_word{
min_count_of_word=count_of_word
}
return min_count_of_word
}
```

Let me know if this is what you want, i will bring you the code then.